# Unable to use Ipcam function in batch processing

Tags: matlab, batch-processing, ip-camera

I am using batch processing in matlab to run a function in the background.

This is the fucntion which simply captures an image and saves it:

```
function = captureImg(URL)

cam = ipcam(URL);

img = snapshot(cam);

imwrite(img,'newImg.jpg');


end
```

The function captureImg works fine but when I use batch to run it I get an error:

```
job = batch(@captureImg , 0, {'HTTP://192.168.0.49'})

Error: Unable to load a message catalog 'matlab:ipcamera:ipcam'. Please check the file location and 
                       format.
```